# Uniqueness of quotients in semigroup with divisibility?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, divisibility, semigroups, quasigroups

Let $G$ be a semigroup, e.g., a set with an associative binary operation. Suppose further that $G$ has the *divisibility property*, e.g., for all $x,y\in G$ there exist $\ell,r\in G$ such that $\ell x=y$ and $xr=y$.

**How can we prove that $\ell$ and $r$ are unique?**

---

Ignoring associativity, this is almost the definition of a quasigroup; it only lacks the assumption that the $\ell$ and $r$ above are unique. On the [nLab page for quasigroups](http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/quasigroup), the following claim is made:

> Note that we must specify, in the definition, that $\ell$ and $r$ are unique; without associativity, we cannot prove this.

So the implication is that **with** associativity, one can prove the uniqueness of $\ell$ and $r$. But I don't see how this follows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To prove that $\ell$ is unique, it suffices to prove that the semigroup is right cancellative ($a x = b x$ implies $a = b$), since then $\ell_1 x = y$ and $\ell_2 x = y$ implies that $\ell_ 1 x = \ell_2 x$ and $\ell_1 = \ell_2$.

We first show that the semigroup has a right unit. Consider any element $a$. There is some $e$ such that $a e = a$. I claim that $b e = b$ for any $b$. This is because there is some $x$ such that $x a = b$, so $b e = x a e = x a = b$.

Now if $a x = b x$, there is some $y$ such that $x y = e$, so $a = a e = a x y = b x y = b e = b$.